# Masonry - Extra Space Between Grid Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am working on a dev version of a site and am trying to integrate Masonry with Pure.css to create a responsive grid that has the stacking appearance of Masonry. Sometimes it works, but many times I get extra spaces between the grid boxes. If I resize my browser or run through infinite scroll it seems to reset nicely, but the initial load is often off. I've tried implementing imagesLoaded, adding a $(window).load directive along with numerous other methods. I've even waited several seconds after everything has loaded to initialize masonry, and even then it was off.

Here is my masonry function:

```
function mason() {
    $('#deals').imagesLoaded(function(){
        $('#deals').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.outerdeal',
            columnWidth: '.outerdeal',
            containerStyle: null,
            isResizable: true
        }); 
   });
}
```

This is used for initialization. It is reloaded with $('#deals).masonry('reload'). I'm not sure if there are conflicts due to Pure.css (http://purecss.io/). Here is a link to the site with the bug: http://162.243.7.235/nyc

Comment: Masonry can't detect the size of the image and imagesLoaded (like you've tried) rarely work. In the past I have set a min-height for a container that has the image inside of it then set the overflow to hidden.

Comment: This seems to be on the right track. If I force the image height it does render correctly, but since the images are different heights I'm temporarily having to run a jquery function that sets the height of each img tag to the height of the image. After this I can initiate masonry and it seems to work better.